# Exception raised if the table has no rows

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In my if statement below I need to check if in the first tables first row/column  contains a string but I get an exception if the table has no rows.

the exception is:

> "System.IndexOutOfRangeException = {"There is no row at position 0."}"

Code snippet:

```
'if the table has no rows then an exception happens here
If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0).ToString <> "MyMessage" then


'do this - redirect

Else

 myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0) = "no message"

End If
```

Can you help please?

Comment: what's the exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It throws an exception because you're assuming a row exists with the following statement `If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0)`

You should check that you have a row first by doing `If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `if..else` block inside an `if` as:

```
if myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 then 
//your code here
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)` if there's no row in the resultset. Check the row count first:

```vb
If myDataSet.Tables.Count <> 0 AND myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
    ' your code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if your table has any rows

```
If myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 then

'do stuff
```